# How to get JSON data from the Gmail API?

Tags: php, json, gmail-api

How do you get the Gmail API to return json data in php? I have tried to json_encode the data, but only a fraction of the data is returned encoded while the rest doesn't show up. The Gmail API says I can use an 'alt' parameter to change the return type, but I am not sure how to include it in the get function the documentation provides.

```
function getMessage($service, $userId, $messageId) {
        try {
            $message = $service->users_messages->get($userId, $messageId);
            print 'Message with ID: ' . $message->getId() . ' retrieved.';
            return $message;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

The array result is:

```
Google_Service_Gmail_Message Object ( [collection_key:protected] => labelIds [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array ( ) [historyId]
=> 1785321 [id] => 1559c18decd5dd2f [internalDate] => 1467202684000 [labelIds] => Array ( [0] => INBOX [1] => CATEGORY_PERSONAL ) [payloadType:protected] => Google_Service_Gmail_MessagePart [payloadDataType:protected] => [raw] => [sizeEstimate] => 64367 [snippet] => From: "United Airlines, Inc. " <unitedairlines@united.com> Date: June 28, 2016 at 11: [threadId] => 1559c18decd5dd2f [modelData:protected] => Array ( [payload] => Array ( [mimeType] => multipart/alternative [filename] => [headers] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Delivered-To [value] => sujay.garlanka@gmail.com ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Received [value]
=> by 10.55.141.70 with SMTP id p67csp1194499qkd; Wed, 29 Jun 2016 05:18:43 -0700 (PDT) ) [2] => Array ( [name] => X-Received [value] => by 10.157.0.41 with SMTP id 38mr5226713ota.81.1467202723587; Wed, 29 Jun 2016 05:18:43 -0700 (PDT) ) [3] => Array ( [name] => Return-Path [value] => ) [4] => Array ( [name] => Received [value] => from BAY004-OMC3S3.hotmail.com (bay004-omc3s3.hotmail.com. [65.54.190.141]) by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id h22si2854830otd.57.2016.06.29.05.18.43 (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA bits=128/128); Wed, 29 Jun 2016 05:18:43 -0700 (PDT) ) [5] => Array ( [name] => Received-SPF [value] => pass (google.com: domain of sgarlanka@hotmail.com designates 65.54.190.141 as permitted sender) client-ip=65.54.190.141; ) [6] => Array ( [name] => Authentication-Results [value] => mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of sgarlanka@hotmail.com designates 65.54.190.141 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=sgarlanka@hotmail.com; dmarc=pass (p=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=hotmail.com ) [7] => Array ( [name] => Received [value] => from BAY407-EAS15 ([65.54.190.189]) by BAY004-OMC3S3.hotmail.com over TLS secured channel with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.23008); Wed, 29 Jun 2016 05:18:06 -0700 ) [8] => Array ( [name] => X-TMN [value] => [qVu+KA1HzBjVEnm8pt4D52R4whDEnRzF] ) [9] => Array ( [name] => X-Originating-Email [value] => [sgarlanka@hotmail.com] ) [10] => Array ( [name] => Message-ID [value] => ) [11] => Array ( [name] => Return-Path [value] => sgarlanka@hotmail.com ) [12] => Array ( [name]
=> Content-Type [value] => multipart/alternative; boundary="Apple-Mail-7E50522D-FBB8-497E-AF1E-D257FAB1BB30" ) [13] => Array ( [name] => Content-Transfer-Encoding [value] => 7bit ) [14] => Array ( [name] => From [value] => Sudhakar Garlanka ) [15] => Array ( [name] => MIME-Version [value] => 1.0 (1.0) ) [16] => Array ( [name]
=> Date [value] => Wed, 29 Jun 2016 08:18:04 -0400 ) [17] => Array ( [name] => Subject [value] => My Chicago trip ) [18] => Array ( [name]
=> To [value] => Madhu Garlanka , Madhu Garlanka , Sujay Garlanka ) [19] => Array ( [name] => X-OriginalArrivalTime [value] => 29 Jun 2016 12:18:06.0148 (UTC) FILETIME=[4A752840:01D1D200] ) ) [body] => Array ( [size] => 0 ) [parts] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [partId] => 0 [mimeType] => text/plain [filename] => [headers] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Content-Type [value] => text/plain; charset="utf-8" ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Content-Transfer-Encoding [value] => base64 ) ) [body] => Array ( [size] => 3307 [data] => DQoNCj4gRnJvbTogIlVuaXRlZCBBaXJsaW5lcywgSW5jLiAiIDx1bml0ZWRhaXJsaW5lc0B1bml0ZWQuY29tPg0KPiBEYXRlOiBKdW5lIDI4LCAyMDE2IGF0IDExOjI5OjUwIFBNIEVEVA0KPiBUbzogc2dhcmxhbmthQGhvdG1haWwuY29tDQo-IFN1YmplY3Q6IHVuaXRlZC5jb20gcmVzZXJ2YXRpb24gZm9yIENoaWNhZ28sIElMLCBVUyAoT1JEIC0gTydIYXJlKQ0KPiANCj4gDQo-IEFkZCBVbml0ZWRBaXJsaW5lc0BuZXdzLnVuaXRlZC5jb20gdG8geW91ciBhZGRyZXNzIGJvb2suIFNlZSBpbnN0cnVjdGlvbnMuDQo-IA0KPiAgCVR1ZXNkYXksIEp1bmUgMjgsIDIwMTYNCj4gRmxpZ2h0IGl0aW5lcmFyeSBmb3Igc3VkaGFrYXIgZ2FybGFua2ENCj4gDQo-IAlzdWRoYWthciBnYXJsYW5rYSBoYXMgc2hhcmVkIHRoaXMgdXBjb21pbmcgVW5pdGVkIGZsaWdodCBpdGluZXJhcnkgd2l0aCB5b3UuDQo-ICAJTWVzc2FnZToNCj4gQ29uZmlybWF0aW9uIG51bWJlcjoNCj4gDQo-IE1DV0NUQg0KPiAgDQo-IFdhc2hpbmd0b24sIERDLCBVUyAoSUFEIC0gRHVsbGVzKQ0KPiB0byBDaGljYWdvLCBJTCwgVVMgKE9SRCAtIE8nSGFyZSkNCj4gVHJpcCBzdW1tYXJ5DQo-IA0KPiBGcmksIEp1bCAwMSwgMjAxNg0KPiANCj4gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCVVBIDUxMQ0KPiBOb25zdG9wDQo-IDU6MDUgcG0NCj4gV2FzaGluZ3RvbiwgREMsIFVTIChJQUQgLSBEdWxsZXMpDQo-IAkNCj4gNjoyMCBwbQ0KPiBDaGljYWdvLCBJTCwgVVMgKE9SRCAtIE8nSGFyZSkNCj4gRHVyYXRpb246IDJoIDE1bQ0KPiBVbml0ZWQgRWNvbm9teSAoTSkNCj4gU25hY2tzIGZvciBQdXJjaGFzZQ0KPiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAJV2ktRmkJICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAJUG93ZXIgb3V0bGV0cw0KPiBNb24sIEp1bCAwNCwgMjAxNg0KPiANCj4gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCVVBIDYzMg0KPiBOb25zdG9wDQo-IDg6NDQgYW0NCj4gQ2hpY2FnbywgSUwsIFVTIChPUkQgLSBPJ0hhcmUpDQo-IAkNCj4gMTE6MzQgYW0NCj4gV2FzaGluZ3RvbiwgREMsIFVTIChJQUQgLSBEdWxsZXMpDQo-IER1cmF0aW9uOiAxaCA1MG0NCj4gVW5pdGVkIEVjb25vbXkgKE0pDQo-IFNuYWNrcyBmb3IgUHVyY2hhc2UNCj4gVHJhdmVsZXJzDQo-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-IFBsZWFzZSBkbyBub3QgcmVwbHkgdG8gdGhpcyBlLW1haWwsIGFzIGl0IGNhbm5vdCBiZSBhbnN3ZXJlZCBmcm9tIHRoaXMgYWRkcmVzcy4NCj4gDQo-IEZvciBjaGFuZ2VzICh3aGljaCBtYXkgcmVzdWx0IGluIGEgZmFyZSBjaGFuZ2UpIG9yIHF1ZXN0aW9ucyBhYm91dCB5b3VyIHJlc2VydmF0aW9uLCB5b3UgbWF5IGNvbnRhY3QgdW5pdGVkLmNvbSBTdXBwb3J0IHZpYSB0ZWxlcGhvbmUgYXQgMS04ODgtNDkxLTY1NzMgaW4gdGhlIFUuUy4gYW5kIENhbmFkYSBvciBpbiB0aGUgVW5pdGVkIEtpbmdkb20gYXQgMDgwMC0wMjgtNTAwMy4gRWxzZXdoZXJlLCBwbGVhc2UgY29udGFjdCBVbml0ZWQgUmVzZXJ2YXRpb25zLg0KPiANCj4gVGhhbmsgeW91IGZvciB1c2luZyB1bml0ZWQuY29tDQo-IA0KPiB1bml0ZWQuY29tDQo-ICANCj4gRGVhbHMgJiBvZmZlcnMNCj4gIA0KPiBSZXNlcnZhdGlvbnMNCj4gIA0KPiBFYXJuIG1pbGVzDQo-IE15IGFjY291bnQNCj4gU1RBWSBDT05ORUNURUQNCj4gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAkgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCSAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAJICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIAkgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgCSAJIA0KPiAgDQo-IENvcHlyaWdodCDCqSAyMDE2IFVuaXRlZCBBaXJsaW5lcywgSW5jLkFsbCBSaWdodHMgUmVzZXJ2ZWQNCj4gVmlldyBvdXIgUHJpdmFjeSBQb2xpY3kuDQo-IA0KPiBFLW1haWwgSW5mb3JtYXRpb24NCj4gUGxlYXNlIGRvIG5vdCByZXBseSB0byB0aGlzIG1lc3NhZ2UgdXNpbmcgdGhlICJyZXBseSIgYWRkcmVzcy4NCj4gVGhlIGluZm9ybWF0aW9uIGNvbnRhaW5lZCBpbiB0aGlzIGUtbWFpbCBpcyBpbnRlbmRlZCBmb3IgdGhlIG9yaWdpbmFsIHJlY2lwaWVudCBvbmx5Lg0KPiBVbml0ZWQgTWlsZWFnZVBsdXMNCj4gOTAwIEdyYW5kIFBsYXphIERyLg0KPiBIb3VzdG9uLCBUWCA3NzA2NyBVU0ENCg== ) ) [1] => Array ( [partId] => 1 [mimeType] => text/html [filename] => [headers] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Content-Type [value] => text/html; charset="utf-8" ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Content-Transfer-Encoding [value] => base64 ) ) [body] => Array ( [size] => 42158 [data] => 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
```

The JSON encoded result is:

> {"historyId":"1785524","id":"1559c18decd5dd2f","internalDate":"1467202684000","labelIds":["INBOX","CATEGORY_PERSONAL"],"raw":null,"sizeEstimate":64367,"snippet":"From:
>   "United Airlines, Inc. "  Date: June 28,
>   2016 at 11:","threadId":"1559c18decd5dd2f"}

Comment: `json_decode` turns the JSON string into an array, `json_encode` turns it back into a JSON string

Comment: The problem is json_encode only returns part of the array encoded in JSON while the rest does not show up.

Comment: Can you add your JSON encoded result to your question, along with a var_dump() of your JSON object/array

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're using this?

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get#parameters

If so, are you setting the format parameter correctly, to either full (which seems to put body content in the payload field) or raw (which is a full dump to a single field)?

It looks like full is the default, so "payload" should have all your data...